# Marklogic - Update within an array of element of a json using java api

Tags: json, jackson, marklogic, marklogic-8

Lets say we have json looks like

```
{ 
   "name":"abc", 
   "lastName":"xyz", 
   "description":"aaaaa aaaa", 
   "dob":11-10-1988,
   "workInformation":[
       {
          "address":"kolkata", 
          "workFor":"vvv Pvt Ltd",
          "reference" : [
              {
                 "refName" : "ttt",
                 "refId" : "12345"
              },
               {
                 "refName" : "sss",
                 "refId" : "23412"
              }
          ]
       },
        {
          "address":"bangalore", 
          "workFor":"www Pvt Ltd",
          "reference" : [
              {
                 "refName" : "rrr",
                 "refId" : "43434"
              },
               {
                 "refName" : "yyyy",
                 "refId" : "34213"
              }
          ]
       },
       {
          "address":"delhi", 
          "workFor":"sss Pvt Ltd",
          "reference" : [
              {
                 "refName" : "qqqq",
                 "refId" : "76767"
              },
               {
                 "refName" : "gggg",
                 "refId" : "65432"
              }
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

I have tried insertFragment of DocumentPatchBuilder. Using this i am able to update before/after of the json properties. But i have to insert inside the property workInformation which is of array type. Here is the insertFragment example which i tried -

```
 DocumentPatchBuilder pb = docMgr.newPatchBuilder();
 pb.pathLanguage(DocumentPatchBuilder.PathLanguage.JSONPATH);
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 pb.insertFragment("workInformation", Position.BEFORE,mapper.createObjectNode().put("hello", "hai"));
```

I wanted to insert data mentioned below inside the **workInformation** section using java api -

```
   {
          "address":"Mumbai", 
          "workFor":"zzz Pvt Ltd"
   }
```

Please let me know how to do it.

Thanks for Reading.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in server-side JavaScript?  Then it's a simple `var x = fn.doc(...); x['workInformation'].push({'address': ...}); xdmp.save(...)`. SJS works extremely well with JSON.

Comment: I want to do it in Java API. If you could refer any example/documentation it will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To insert inside the workInformation array, you would need to specify the position as POSITION.LAST_CHILD to insert it as the last child of the child list of the context. Also, you would need to specify "workInformation" as an array type in the first argument of patchBuilder.insertFragment - ["workInformation"]. The code would be something like:

```
DocumentPatchBuilder pb = docMgr.newPatchBuilder();
pb.pathLanguage(DocumentPatchBuilder.PathLanguage.JSONPATH);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectNode fragmentNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
fragmentNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
fragmentNode.put("address", "mumbai");
fragmentNode.put("workFor", "zzz Pvt Ltd");
String fragment = mapper.writeValueAsString(fragmentNode);

pb.insertFragment("$.[\"workInformation\"]", Position.LAST_CHILD, fragment);
```

This should do the trick and this would insert

```
{
    "address":"Mumbai", 
    "workFor":"zzz Pvt Ltd"
}
```

at the end of "workInformation" property.

Comment: Vivek I have to insert fragment in array of array. I have updated my json, now it contains reference array inside the workInformation array. I have tried  pb.insertFragment("$.[\"workInformaiton\"][1].[\"reference\"]", Position.LAST_CHILD, fragment); It is not working. Can you tell me how to make it work with array of array type.

Comment: I have tried this and it worked - [\"workInformaiton\"][0][\"reference\"]